# Django Avatars referencing images by absolute file system path on local (django-avatar)

Tags: django

I am trying to install django-avatar in my Django installation. What I cannot figure out for the life of me is where I'm going wrong with the MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL paths.

Avatars are currently being uploaded to the correct location on my local: **<* project *>/media/avatars/...**

However, when I hit **/avatars/change/** the Images are being served using local absolute paths:

/Users/<* username *>/<* project_path *>/media/avatars/....jpg

In my settings.py I have the following variables set:

```
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
AVATAR_STORAGE_DIR = MEDIA_ROOT + '/avatars/'
```

And in my urls.py I have:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
            'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
        }),
        url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
            'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT,
        }),
    )
```

I think the problem must be at the application level rather than in my project settings. If anyone could help that would be amazing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience, this is standard behavior when using the development server. The Django development server is serving the static files and does so from the MEDIA_ROOT (the full local path).

When deploying, static files should be served with your web server and the URL's will reflect the MEDIA_URL you're expecting.

May be worth reading over Django's docs on [managing static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/).